# proxy_read_timeout setting not affecting Nginx (Kong)

Tags: nginx, kong

We use kong as our API gateway and have some endpoints that take longer than 60 seconds to respond. According to the Nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout), I can change this with `proxy_read_timeout`, but this setting is not having any impact and I don't know why.

We use kong as a docker container. Here is the excerpt of the Dockerfile

```
FROM mashape/kong:0.9.5
COPY nginx.conf.custom /usr/local/kong/nginx.conf.custom
COPY nginx-kong.conf.custom /usr/local/kong/nginx-kong.conf.custom
...
```

Our nginx-kong.conf.custom file is the same as the default except for the excerpt below, in the location / block.

```
location / {
    set $upstream_host nil;
    set $upstream_url nil;

    access_by_lua_block {
        kong.access()
    }

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $upstream_host;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_pass $upstream_url;

    proxy_read_timeout 180s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 75s;

    header_filter_by_lua_block {
        kong.header_filter()
    }

    body_filter_by_lua_block {
        kong.body_filter()
    }

    log_by_lua_block {
        kong.log()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this page help https://getkong.org/docs/0.10.x/configuration/ ? Or, if not, we welcome PRs to improve the docs - you can find that page's source here https://github.com/Mashape/getkong.org/blob/master/app/docs/0.10.x/configuration.md